# Provided dependency and JBOSS EAP 7

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I understand that PROVIDED dependencies are "provided" by container and application don't need generate this JAR.

1) So, I'm using JBOSS EAP 7.0.0.GA and this have the following jar in this module folder: **hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar**.

In my project i'm using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9.Final-redhat-1</version>
        </dependency>
```

It works fine, without errors. But i understand that i should use "PROVIDED" scope because this jar is provided by container. Why it works ?

2) I have another example. In Jboss Eap 7.0.0.GA i have the following jar: **jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final-redhat-1.jar**. But in my project i have the following:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

It works fine too, but i don't understand why. To me the correct dependency should be servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final-redhat-1 with provided. Why it works too ?

Answer (score 1):

At build time, Maven will resolve the dependencies and make the relevant packages available to the compiler. Your appserver may provide, for example, JARs that contain the classes and interfaces in `javax.servlet`, but these classes won't necessarily be useful to the compiler, because it doesn't know where they are. By providing the dependencies to Maven, you're having Maven find its own implementations of these dependencies, just for use at compile time.

At run time, if you've marked the dependencies as `provided`, then your application will use the versions provided by the appserver, rather than the versions known to Maven. This is potentially a bad thing, but it often works because the compiler really needs to know only the method signatures, not their implementations. The method signatures of classes that are controlled by specifications, such as those in `javax.servlet`, change only infrequently, so the mismatch between the compile-time JARs and run-time JARs may go unnoticed. Unlike OSGi-compliant JARs, JARs built for JEE do not contain meta-data that specifies particular compatible dependency versions -- JEE classloaders will use what they find, for better or worse.

You can be caught out, however -- particularly if the mismatch is substantial. Problems may be very obvious at runtime, such as exceptions related to missing classes or methods, but they can be subtle.

It's therefore often best, where practicable, to use the same compile-time versions of dependencies as the versions that will be available at runtime. For EAP, I recall that Red Hat distributes a Maven bill-of-materials (BOM) file that specifies all the versions of all the EAP JARs for specific EAP releases.

Comment: Can you give me a real example to understand better the situation?

Comment: So, if all my dependency work without 'provided' scope, why i need provided ? Just for a lightweight JAR ?

Comment: If you add your own dependencies into the JAR, then you run the risk of having classes with the same name, but different versions, available to the application. Unless you study the JEE class loading rules in great detail -- and the appserver actually respects then -- it's going to be awkward to tell which class will be loaded at runtime. So it's not just a case of a lighter JAR, but having consistency at run time.

Comment: I have a jar that take care about all hibernate stuff. This jar is used in all my projects and i dont need re-declare hibernate dependencies. Because it i setted compile scope in all dependencies. Do you see another solution?

Comment: I guess you're including Hibernate classes in your JAR, right? Are they the same version as EAP provides, or different? If they are different, you may get away with it, depending on how different they are. What happens if you use `provided` so that the EAP versions are used? Does you application not work?

Comment: The version of my dependency is exactly the same as EAP. If i use provided i'm forcing all projects to declare hibernate stuff

Comment: I would need to know a lot more about how you're structuring your builds, to figure out why this is. It probably won't hurt to include the Hibernate bits in your JAR, if it's the same as the appserver version, except by making the JAR larger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156015/discussion-between-ronaldolanhellas-and-kevin-boone).